# REST-API how to check which product added by which customer or consumer?

Tags: php, web-services, api, magento, rest

I have script to add product into Magento using REST-API

My code:

```
<?php
class RestApiProduct {

    private $productData;
    private $consumerKey;
    private $consumerSecret;
    private $secret;
    private $token;
    private $config;
    private $authType;
    private $resourceUrl;
    private $headerType = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');

    public $responceInfo;
    public $responce;
    public $oauthError;
    public $productID;

    function __construct($configFile='config.ini'){
        $this->config = parse_ini_file($configFile, true);
        if(count($this->config)<5) {
            $this->responce="Please configure with getAccessToken setup";
            return false;
        }

        $this->basepath = $this->config['basepath'];
        $this->consumerKey = $this->config['consumerKey'];
        $this->consumerSecret = $this->config['consumerSecret'];
        $this->secret = $this->config['secret'];
        $this->token = $this->config['token'];
        $this->authType = OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION;
        $this->resourceUrl = $this->basepath.'api/rest/products';
    }

    function setProduct($data){
        $this->productData=json_encode($data);
    }

    function saveProduct(){
        try {
            $oauthClient = new OAuth($this->consumerKey, $this->consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $this->authType);
            $oauthClient->enableDebug();
            $oauthClient->setToken($this->token, $this->secret);

            $oauthClient->fetch($this->resourceUrl, $this->productData, "POST", $this->headerType);

            $this->responceInfo = $oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo();
            $this->responce = $oauthClient->getLastResponse();

        } catch (OAuthException $e) {
            $this->oauthError=$e;
        }
    }
}

$restObj= new RestApiProduct();
$restObj->setProduct($productArray);
$restObj->saveProduct();


$restObj2= new RestApiProduct('secondConfig.ini');
$restObj2->setProduct($productArray);
$restObj2->saveProduct();

?>
```

Now if i have two config file (run one bye one) with two different configuration of consumer Key and secret also access Token and secret.

than how to identify which product added by which consumer?